# Is "to come up with smth." considered colloquial?

Tags: colloquialisms

In my opinion, a sentence such as

> "Therefore, one should *come up with* another solution."

too informal for something like a technical report or scientific article. Is it indeed usually considered as colloquial language?

Answer (score 2):

Probably. Unless you are quoting dialogue, it would be better in writing to request that someone **"research"** alternative solutions, than "come up with" them.

Comment: *research* does not quite mean *come up with*; a closer match is *find*. Although maybe *research* is what the OP wants to say.

Comment: @Peter Shor - Touché... Mea culpa.

Comment: Yes indeed, that's what I was referring to!